# Hide ArcMap Main Menu

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, c#

Is there a way to hide the ArcMap Main Menu either by customizing ArcMap manually or programmatically? I’ve tried to use the customization dialog and disable the Main Menu which didn’t work.

Trying to do it programmatically in the `IApplicationStatusEvents_Event.Initialized` didn’t work, too.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars;
if (commandBars != null)
{
    commandBars.HideAllToolbars();
}
```

Additionally I would like to be able to restore the Main Menu easyly if a support task makes it necessary.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to make a standalone app using ArcGIS Engine. The SDK has a visual studio template project for a simple mapviewer.

Comment: Tanks for that quick answer. I’ve never build a standalone app including a map before. In my current project (it is nearly finalized) I’m using a lot of the ArcMap standard functions like the TOC, HTML popup, the edit templates (IEditTemplate), several edit events and so on. For the future: can you estimate if one can easily use this stuff in an standalone app, too? The hiding of the Main Menu is “nice to have” but I think in my case it will not justify a reprogramming in that late project phase.

Comment: Editing capability would require major effort to implement in Engine.  If you can't hide the main menu, maybe just try removing as many menuitems as possible.